# How to auto update date in powerpoint to last day of previous month

Tags: vba, powerpoint-2013

I need to figure out how to automatically update a range of dates that is in powerpoint 2013. Currently its from Jan 2017- March 31, 2017 but every month i need to update the dates to go through the end of the previous month. So for May i will need Jan 1, 2017 through April 30, 2017.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to run this, you should have a shape called "date" in your slide master.

```
Sub showDate()
Dim date1, date2, d1, y1, d2 As Date
Dim m1, m2 As String

date1 = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) - 4, 1)
date2 = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 0)

d1 = Day(date1)
m1 = MonthName(Month(date1))
y1 = Year(date1)

d2 = Day(date2)
m2 = MonthName(Month(date2))

ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Shapes("date").TextFrame.TextRange = m1 & " " & d1 & ", " & y1 & " - " & m2 & " " & d2 & ", " & Year(date2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I **think** the OP's intention is for `date1 = DateSerial(Year(Now) - IIf(Month(Now) = 1, 1, 0), 1, 1)` as they say the dates were 1 January to 31 March and need to become 1 January to 30 April once the current month is May.  You can also simplify the formatting of the dates by using `Format(date1, "mmmm d, yyyy")` instead of using `m1 & " " & d1 & ", " & y1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub BuildDateRange()

    Dim dateFrom As Date
        dateFrom = DateValue("01/01/2017")

    Dim dateTo As Date
        dateTo = DateAdd("y", -1, DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1))

    While dateFrom <= dateTo

        'add <dateFrom> to your date range...

        dateFrom = DateAdd("y", 1, dateFrom)
    Wend

End Sub
```